# How to detect dark mode in Delphi macOS apps

Tags: macos, delphi, macos-big-sur, darkmode

How to detect dark mode in Delphi FireMonkey macOS (e.g. Big Sur) apps?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FireMonkey platform services to get that information:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform;

function GetSystemTheme: TSystemThemeKind;
var
  LService: IFMXSystemAppearanceService;
begin
  Result := TSystemThemeKind.Unspecified;
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXSystemAppearanceService, LService) then
    Result := LService.GetSystemThemeKind;
end;
```

Where `TSystemThemeKind` is declared as

```
TSystemThemeKind = (Unspecified, Light, Dark);
```

`IFMXSystemAppearanceService` is currently supported on Android, iOS and macOS.

Comment: Wow. thanks.If we want to return to the program automatically?? what do we do.

Comment: Do you mean put the above code in the function? Yes, you can do that easily. I modified the example.

Comment: So is it by now supporting Windows too or not? Else one could add a platform specific implementation using https://blogs.embarcadero.com/easily-customize-your-delphi-vcl-application-with-dark-and-light-themes-according-to-windows-mode/

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis It is still not supported by FMX in Delphi 11.1, the blog post talks about VCL application. There is a feature request in Quality Portal you can vote for https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-37290

Comment: I guess it's not important if that sample is for VCL, the main info is the registry key via which one can get that. So one can add an implementation of that platform service for Windows. Might take a stab at it if I have time and contribute to Embarcadero

Comment: this is also useful for reusing the detection code: also useful: https://blogs.embarcadero.com/modernize-your-app-are-you-handling-windows-themes-correctly/ - mentions DarkMode library. Also note there's a Windows message to detect a change that one could use. Not sure if the FMX service also supports reacting on the fly to changes of the light/dark mode or just support querying the state